# Optimizing PHP - does using array_keys() in foreach loops really increase performance?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I read in a few different articles that using array_keys() in foreach loops increases performance, but in practice I really don't notice any increase in speed of my code when using array_keys() on large arrays.

example:

```
foreach(array_keys($myArray) as $ak){
   $arrayElement =& $myArray[$ak];
   //do whatever I need to do with massive array ...
}
```

Comment: This is not the kind of stuff you'll notice, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat logical to have some performance gain with large arrays - yes. That way PHP will only copy the array keys in the loop as opposed to keys+values, resulting in a less memory-intensive procedure.

However, as it's been noted in the comments section - it's not something that you'll usually notice. It's deffinately a good practice to make a habit for those things, but you can't actually see it outside of benchmark scores unless you're writing a fairly complex/heavy script.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'm using this on a fairly massive array, so I thought I would see some sort of noticeable performance gain. I do see the timer I threw on the page go down a little bit though.